# Is list function a good candidate for my scenario?

Tags: couchdb

I have a view in couchDb that is defined like this

```
 function (doc) {
 if (doc.url) {
     var a = new Date(doc.postedOn);
     emit([a.toLocaleDateString(), doc.count, doc.userId], {
         _id: doc.userId,
         postTitle: doc.postTitle,
         postSummary: doc.postSummary,
         url: doc.url,
         count: doc.count
     });
  }
};
```

This gives me the result in a format that I want.Sorted first by date then by count and then by userID.

However I have trouble querying it.What I want is to query this view just by userId.That is leave the date and the count parameter null.

```
 _view/viewName?limit=20&descending=true&endkey=["","","userId"]
```

does not give me the desired result.

Should I be using [list function](http://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ddocs.html#list-functions) to filter out the results of the view.Is there any impact on performance if I do this?

This quote from the [definitive guide](http://guide.couchdb.org/editions/1/en/transforming.html) first gave me the idea that list functions could be used to filter and aggregate results.

> The powerful iterator API allows for flexibility to filter and aggregate rows on the fly, as well as output raw transformations for an easy way to make Atom feeds, HTML lists, CSV files, config files, or even just modified JSON.

Comment: If you want to query by `userId`, why is it the last value in the `key` you emit? CouchDB doesn't support a query with wild-cards  (your query would only work when the first two values are `""`).

Comment: Well I wanted to create  specific sort order.First by date,then by count and then by id.As suggested by @NikitaVolkov I have changed my view.One other thing that I noticed is instead of passing two "" I should pass {}.Seems to work but I don't know why.I will add an answer to this once I am sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List function has nothing to do with your case. From the docs you've linked to yourself:

- > While Show functions are used to customize document presentation, List functions are used for same purpose, but against View functions results.
- > Show functions are used to represent documents in various formats, commonly as HTML page with nicer formatting. They can also be used to run server-side functions without requiring a pre-existing document.

To solve your problem just change the order of the emitted keys, putting `userId` first, i.e.:

```
[ doc.userId, a.toLocaleDateString(), doc.count ]
```

and update your query appropriately.

If changing the order of emitted keys is not an option, just create another view.

Comment: No it still does not work.Even after updating the view,querying for userId has no effect.Like before the result of all the userId are returned sorted by date and count.Am I querying it wrong?

Comment: @AkshatJiwanSharma Most probably. Check whether you're [using the `startkey` and `descending` correctly](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html#reversed).

Comment: Instead of empty strings I had to query with {} like so *viewName?startkey=[userId,{}]*